# Same formula, different result

Tags: excel-formula

[image]
The formula is exactly the same in both yellow cells. both are text.
Why is the result different?

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",A1:A4)),"bb",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("d",A1:A4)),"cc","ee"))
```

With some chages, still same problem. I don't understand.
[image]

Comment: are there any trailing spaces in cells A1:A4?

Comment: no just a letter

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: cell b2 shows correct result. b1, b3, and b4 should also display bb. aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

The function `SEARCH` returns a result for every cell in the given range (A1:A4). To get only one result, you can wrap it with `OR` to check whether any cell contains the text you are searching for.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",A1:A4))),"bb",IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("d",A1:A4))),"cc","ee"))
```

Or just search for one cell at a time:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",A1)),"bb",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("d",A1)),"cc","ee"))
```